# Adding a column from the original data frame to a groupby data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame df1 with data that looks like this:

```
      Item Store Sales Dept 
   0  1     1     5     A
   1  1     2     3     A
   2  1     3     4     A
   3  2     1     3     A
   4  2     2     3     A
```

I then want to use group by to see the total sales by item:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Item']).agg({'Item':'first','Sales':'sum'})
```

Which gives me:

```
      Item Sales  
   0  1     12     
   1  2     6
```

And then I add a column with the rank of the item in terms of number of sales:

```
 df2['Item Rank'] = df2['Sales'].rank(ascending=False,method='min').astype(int)
```

So that I get:

```
      Item Sales Item Rank 
   0  1     12       1
   1  2     6        2
```

I now want to add the Dept column to df2, so that I have

```
      Item Sales Item Rank Dept 
   0  1     12       1      A
   1  2     6        2      A
```

But everything I have tried has failed. 
I either get an empty column, when I try to add the column in from the beginning,  or a df with the wrong size if I try to concatenate the new df with the column from the original df.

Comment: I think this might be because there's nothing guaranteeing that all item 1 will use Dept `A`. 

Could you not just add it manually rather than concatenating existing dataframes?

Comment: What if the second row i.e. index 1 has `Dept` as `B`. What would you like the output to look like then?

Comment: @Nitred my data is such that that would never occur, the relationship of items to dept is many-to-one.

Comment: What has failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Item']).agg({'Item':'first','Sales':'sum','Dept': 'first'}).\
   assign(Itemrank=df.Sales.rank(ascending=False,method='min').astype(int) )
Out[64]: 
      Item Dept  Sales  Itemrank
Item                            
1        1    A     12         3
2        2    A      6         2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is unusual but if you can add the `Dept` column when you're doing the groupby itself:

A simple option is just to hard code the value if you already know what it needs to be:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Item']).agg({'Item':'first',
                                 'Sales':'sum',
                                 'Dept': lambda x: 'A'})
```

Or you could take it from the dataframe itself:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Item']).agg({'Item':'first',
                                 'Sales':'sum',
                                 'Dept': lambda x: df1['Dept'].iloc[0]})
```